# MongoDB case insensitive query on text with parenthesis

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a very annoying problem with a case insensitive query on mongodb.

I'm using MongoTemplate in a web application and I need to execute case insensitive queries on a collection.

with this code

```
Query q = new Query();
q.addCriteria(Criteria.where("myField")
.regex(Pattern.compile(fieldValue, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE))); 
return mongoTemplate.findOne(q,MyClass.class);
```

I create the following query

```
{ "myField" : { "$regex" : "field value" , "$options" : "iu"}}
```

that works perfectly when I have simple text, for example:

**caPITella CapitatA**

but...but...when there are *parenthesis ()* the query doesn't work.
It doesn't work at all, even the query text is wrote as is wrote in the document...Example:

query 1:

```
{"myField" : "Ceratonereis (Composetia) costae" } -> 1 result (ok)
```

query 2:

```
{ "myField" : { 
    "$regex" : "Ceratonereis (Composetia) costae" , 
   "$options" : "iu"
}} -> no results (not ok)
```

query 3:

```
{ "scientificName" : { 
    "$regex" : "ceratonereis (composetia) costae" ,
    "$options" : "iu"
}}  -> no results (....)
```

So...I'm doing something wrong? I forgot some  Pattern.SOME to include in the Pattern.compile()? Any solution?

Thanks

**------ UPDATE ------**

The answer of user3561036 helped me to figure how the query must be built.

So, I have resolved by modifying the query building in

```
q.addCriteria(Criteria.where("myField")
.regex(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(myFieldValue), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE)));
```

The output query

```
{ "myField" : { "$regex" : "\\Qhaliclona (rhizoniera) sarai\\E" , "$options" : "iu"}}
```

works.

Comment: why did you use `u`("$options" : "iu") in options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator with a "string" as input then you must quote literals for reserved characters such as `()`.

Normally that's a single `\`, but since it's in a string already you do it twice `\\`:

```
{ "myField" : { 
    "$regex" : "Ceratonereis \\(Composetia\\) costae" , 
    "$options" : "iu"
}}
```

Comment: Good, answer...It gave me the input to resolve the issue with:
'Query q = new Query();
q.addCriteria(Criteria.where("myField")
.regex(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(myFieldValue), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE))); '

that give me the output query:
'{ "scientificName" : { "$regex" : "\\Qhaliclona (rhizoniera) sarai\\E" , "$options" : "iu"}}'

which works.

Comment: @dgiaig Well it should have pointed since that's how compile with strings works. The method here is overkill since only chars like `()` are reserved as I said. It's a regex question at heart. Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) your answers.

Comment: @dgiaig That's okay and your welcome. And welcome to stack overflow. It's mostly thankless as is demonstrated by the at present four upvotes and two watchers of your question, but only one vote of approval and your own acceptance ( thanks ) here. So just a preview of what to get used to.

Comment: how do I do it when my string comes dynamically

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but you can use `query.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\/^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");`

This is working with `aggregate` and `matches` :

```
 const order = user_input.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\/^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
 const regex = new RegExp(order, 'i');
 const query = await this.databaseModel.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            name : regex
        }
    // ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $strcasecmp.
The aggregation framework was introduced in MongoDB 2.2. You can use the string operator "$strcasecmp" to make a case-insensitive comparison between strings.
It's more recommended and easier than using regex.