# Java MongoTemplate (How to make search case insensitive)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have query to mongo using java mongotemplate:

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
                .matchingAny(searchText);
Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria);
return mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class, "user");
```

How to make it case insensitive?

I'm using query like this in mongo:

```
db.user.find( { $text: { $search: "John" } } )
```

It search this text in every indexed field. I need to do it case insensitive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935715/mongodb-case-insensitive-query-on-text-with-parenthesis

Comment: The tests [**here**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/mongodb/text-search/src/test/java/example/springdata/mongodb/textsearch/TextSearchTemplateTests.java) mention that _Note that text search is case insensitive and will also find entries like {@literal releases}._

Comment: and how to put case insensitive for TextCriteria? I'm not understood